# Installing a gem hangs with no output on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So, I installed Rails Installer on my machine (Windows).  I just tried to install a gem (nokogiri), but to no avail.  In the cmd window, running `gem install nokogiri` just hangs, provides no status and nothing happens.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What command, specifically, are you running that hangs?

Comment: This is also happening for me.

Answer (score 5):

To know what actually is happening try

```
gem install nokogiri -V
```

Comment: It still hangs for me with no output even with the verbose flag.